# Invalid appsecret_proof error for facebook-sdk-4.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My latest facebook php sdk gives error below:

> Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API
>     argument

Question is asked before but recommendations are generally same and they suggests to comment out related lines on sdk. I can also make sdk work by commenting line `472 in FacebookRequest.php : params['appsecret_proof'] = $this->getAppSecretProof();` . However, I need my sdk work with `appsecret_proof` I think it causes another problem without `appsecret_proof`. I checked source codes of sdk and see that `appsecret_proof` is generated properly but it does not work again and gives invalid `appsecret_proof` error. What is the source of problem here?